# Post Twitter on my Android Application

Tags: android, twitter, location

I'm trying to write a Panic Application program and I need to post twitter my location and a emergency message using just one button.
I created and Twitter_Dialog class that extends Dialog
I can access my twitter and post new things but I haven't succeed posting my location and the string that is saved in my string.xml.

I have tried somthing like this

```
sms_mesaj=input.getText().toString()+" Konumum : http://maps.google.com/?q="+latitude+","+longitude;
new Twitter_Dialog(SmsuyariMainActivity.this,"http://twitter.com/?status="sms_mesaj;
```

But it does not work. 
P.S. : My app also sends SMS so I know for sure I can get latitude and longitude correctly.